# How to grep and redirect hcidump to a file?

Tags: shell, grep

Into my shell script this line do not redirect asc lines recieved by hcidump filtering by l2cap protocol.

When i execute it by command prompt it works fine:

```
hcidump -a l2cap | grep -v -e 'CAP' -e 'HCI'
```

But when redirect to a file using a shell script doesn´t send lines to destination file.

```
hcidump -a l2cap | grep -v -e 'CAP' -e 'HCI' > onlystringsrecieved.txt
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: `-e 'CAP' -e 'HCI'` would mean just `-e 'HCI'` because the last `-e` would win.  Is that what you really need?

Comment: Im needing to get hcidump string using l2cap protocol. But it gets a lot unnecessary lines... I need to clean the input and send it to a file...

Comment: If i use the follow command its works fine:
hcidump -a l2cap > onlystringsrecieved.txt
but with grep ... do not write anything into destination file.

Comment: Can you paste some sample output of below cmd - 
`hcidump -a 12cap |grep -e 'CAP|HCI'`

Comment: Maybe `hcidump -a l2cap` is acting like a loop.. causing your output file to be overwritten in each loop which would mean it will only contain the results of the final loop (quite possible being nothing). Have you tried `hcidump -a l2cap | grep -v -e 'CAP|HCI' >> onlystringsrecieved.txt`. Pay attention to `>>` instead of `>`. Also, given codeforester's and VIPIN's comment I've made a small change to your grep command.

Comment: Try `--line-buffered` options of grep.